# Why is this query so slow and what can i do about it

Tags: mysql

I have the following `SELECT` `UPDATE` statement from `MySQL`

```
UPDATE table_Learning l
INNER JOIN (select ULN, id from table_users group by ULN having count(ULN) =1) u 
ON l.ULN = u.ULN
set l.user_id=u.id
WHERE l.user_id is null
```

The problem is, it is so slow that it times out, and basically does not work.

I am sure it is to do with the line:

```
INNER JOIN (select ULN, id from table_users group by ULN having count(ULN) =1) u
```

and specifically because there is both a `GROUP BY` and a `HAVING` clause in this inner select, and from what I have read, because `INNER JOINS` are very slow with MySQL.

My overall aim is to:

Populate the `userID`'s that are `null` in `table_learning`
To do so using the `userID`'s in `table_users`
To Join on the field named `ULN` in both tables
To only populate the fields where the `ULN` is unique in `table_users` eg if more than one user has this `ULN`, then do not populate the `user_id` in `table_learning`

Comment: Are these innodb tables?

Comment: @EternalHour yes they are

Comment: In that case, the issue is the `HAVING COUNT`. With innodb, the data is not indexed as it is with myisam which can cause a table scan. Please provide an `EXPLAIN` of your query.

Comment: *"from what I have read, because INNER JOINS are very slow with MySQL"* ... uh, wherever you read that, don't read anything else from there.  That simply not true.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is your query:

```
UPDATE table_Learning l INNER JOIN
       (select ULN, id
        from table_users
        group by ULN
        having count(ULN) = 1
       ) u 
       ON l.ULN = u.ULN
    set l.user_id=u.id
    WHERE l.user_id is null;
```

In MySQL, the subquery is going to be expensive.  An index on `table_learning(user_id)` might help a bit.  But filtering inside the subquery could also help:

```
UPDATE table_Learning l INNER JOIN
       (select ULN, id
        from table_users
        where exists (select 1
                      from table_learning tl
                      where tl.ULN = u.uln and tl.user_id is null
                     )
        group by ULN
        having count(ULN) = 1
       ) u 
       ON l.ULN = u.ULN
    set l.user_id=u.id
    WHERE l.user_id is null;
```

For this, you want a composite index on `table_learning(ULN, user_id)`.